# Recording Video HTML5 not working in Safari and iOS mobile app

Tags: ios, html5-video

I am trying to use the HTML5 video - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video to access camera on the device.

I am following this example - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element to record the video.

It works perfectly in Chrome browser but does not seem to be working on Safari and iOS mobile app.
On debugging both `captureStream()` and `mozCaptureStream()` functions are undefined.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

**PS: Is this a known issue - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=181663. Are there any workarounds? Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think recording webcam as video is an available option on Apple devices.
It might be a licensing issue rather than a technical limitation.

> It works perfectly in Chrome browser but does not seem to be working
> on Safari and iOS mobile app. On debugging both captureStream() and
> mozCaptureStream() functions are undefined.

1. Your link is recording into Google's own **webM** video which is a format **not supported** by Apple. The Safari browser cannot encode pixels as VP8 or VP9 to use inside webM container. Apple has an MPEG video license so for Safari, I expect MP4 to be their expected output (but is there a free H264 encoder inside Safari? Nope).
2. `mozCaptureStream()` is specific to Mozilla Firefox. Safari won't know/accept it.
3. `captureStream()` is [not fully suppported](https://caniuse.com/?search=captureStream) on Safari. The missing part is the recording part.

Possible workarounds:

- Try [enabling MediaRecorder API in Safari](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/how-to-enable-the-mediarecorder-api-for-safari) settings. 
  Research (double-check) for known issues, like as mentioned at bottom of this read this article: https://blog.addpipe.com/safari-support-on-macos-beta/
- If you can draw webcam to Canvas then consider bringing in your own (Javascript-based) H264 encoder (for MP4 video) or VP8/VP9 encoder (for webM video).
- You can try: https://github.com/TrevorSundberg/h264-mp4-encoder.
- Wait for **webCodecs** API to be added to Safari.
   Note in Chrome/Edge you can just use the built-in **webCodecs** API to encode video for MP4 or WebM formats. Safari has no free encoders and thus has no webCodecs API.

Answer (score 0):

I've been banging my head on getting captureStream to work on iOS (Safari and Chrome, same results) to no avail. This reply by @VC.One helped me stop trying to use webM format, which was used by the sample code I was following from mdn which is here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Recording_a_media_element

So I simply switched to mp4 instead of webm, using .srcObject instead of .captureStream, and now I have things working on iOS. I still have a lot of clean-up to do, but when my solution is finished I will make a nice write-up and post back.

Also, someone pointed out that I needed to use the onloadedmetadata with the play method, in order to get a video element to show a real-time feed of bytes from getUserMedia, and that worked. Then I just needed to store the bytes somewhere that iOS will not freak out about (it does not support captureStream) and then it all came together. It definitely seems to be a licensing issue at the heart of it all, which is why this works using mp4 instead of webm.